# How to find the layout type of a view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to avoid `ClassCastException` on doing `this.getLayoutParams()`. Is there a way by which I can get the layout type i.e Relative, Linear or Frame?
Then I would like to use a switch case on the result and then do `this.getLayoutParams()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` operator.

```
if(view instanceof RelativeLayout) {
    // do something
} else if(view instanceof LinearLayout) {
    // do something
} else if(view instanceof FrameLayout) {
    // do something
}
```